# Redis cache class not found

Tags: caching, redis, quarkus

Got the following method:

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "council-tax-bands-by-postcode")
@Query("searchCouncilTaxBandByPostcode")
@Blocking
public Uni<CouncilTax[]> searchByPostcode(CouncilTaxSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    log.infof("Searching council tax bands for postcode: %s", searchCriteria.getPostcode());
    return scraper.getByPostcode(searchCriteria).memoize().indefinitely();
}
```

that leverages redis cache. When I try to start the application is fails with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Lxyz.property.model.CouncilTax;
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:518)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:468)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:518)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:468)
    at io.quarkus.cache.redis.runtime.RedisCacheImpl.loadClass(RedisCacheImpl.java:109)
```

If I remove the redis cache and I use the in-memory one with caffeine works perfectly fine. I tried to set this in application properties:

```
#Cache settings
quarkus.cache.redis.expensiveResourceCache.key-type=java.lang.String
quarkus.cache.redis.expensiveResourceCache.value-type=xyz.property.model.CouncilTax
```

But I got the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Any idea why it tried to load an array of CouncilTax? It would be great if you could provide a complete reproducer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: an array is not supported.